Graphviz bigger arrowheads can look awkward
I'm making a fairly complex, large graph with Graphviz, so i had to increase the arrowhead size to 2. Otherwise they would be nearly invisible when viewing the whole.
This means that sometimes arrowheads can end up like this:

Is there a way to force them to be more like this?

I'm not at liberty to post my complete code unfortunately,  but was wondering if i could get some tips nonetheless
I'm using ortho splines obviously, because the amount of nodes i have would make curved splines sheer chaos, even though this kind of junctions aren't that clear either:

Or maybe there are ways of preventing named chaos; i haven't figured out ranks and groups completely yet.
Plowing through the documentation i couldn't find a way to have ortho splines go diagonal, that might be a feature suggestion, right? ;) or did i miss it somehow?
My defaults:
graph [ fontsize="48", fontname="Arial", labelloc="t" ];
node [ fontsize="24", fontname="Arial", style="filled", fillcolor="aqua", fontname="Arial" ];
edge [ fontsize="24", fontname="Arial", arrowsize="2" ];

I'm sure the color would be frowned upon, but it's OK to me :)
I tried

partitioning the nodes into subgraphs
using group tags to cluster similar nodes
increasing scale by setting nodesep and ranksep,
increasing minlen of edges,
playing around with the value of k
setting overlap="false"; and concentrate="true";

These would all make it slightly better, but it's not perfect yet. Or maybe i expect too much and/or my graph is too complex.
any thoughts would help, thanks! :)

No, there is no way to tell the ortho spline router (or any of the edge routers) to modify the edge positioning based on arrowsize.  Either they will or they won't, but there are no attributes to set.
My guess is that the ortho router is struggling because the nodes and edges are packed too tightly for it.  Don't think it is a bug.
You might try setting arrowsize=1.3 (something greater than 1 and smaller than 2).
As to your more general coaching questions, stackoverflow rules-of-the-road require specific questions and examples of progress-to-date.  (show your work, so to speak)
You might ask these more general questions on the Graphviz forum

You're right. I should only ask if i'm prepared to show the exact code.
Thanks for telling me off gently and trying to help at the same time!
